# Could Aluminum-Based Placoderm-like Tooth Structure Break a Human Skull?

Tags: biology, science-fiction, xenobiology, creature-design

I have a monster in mind, but a major part of its introduction to the story is that I want to have it bite a human soldier's skull clean off. Its teeth are similar in structure to a Placoderm's, but are made of pure aluminum metal. The monster is roughly the size of a human, but is able to overpower a human.

I don't care about armored humans, the unlucky soldier had his helmet fall off while the monster took him down. However, I want the skull to be so highly damaged by the bite the part of the skull in the monster's mouth is either totally cut off from the rest of the skull (IE the person's body falls immediately after the bite), or requires little to no actual force to rip off (Like those little plastic things in frames some games have)

Could Aluminum Teeth like a Placoderm's bite a Human's Skull so as to completely detach to skull?

Comment: [12ft crocodile rips off boy's head](https://www.the-sun.com/news/6793508/massive-crocodile-rips-off-boys-head-body-beasts-stomach/). The aluminum teeth would simply make this easier. Your biggest problem is that a human-sized monster needs a mouth that's big enough to grasp an adult human head. If you're looking to bite it off, it must be big enough to close its mouth over the head. That makes your monster's head perhaps comically bigger than would be expected for its body. Is that OK? As a reference, an adult human head has trouble closing its teeth around a single billiard ball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regulars placoderm that size would have no problem doing it, assuming you mean the bitey placoderms and not the flat ones. Those kinds of placoderms are built for powerful bites. they should be able to generate much greater force than a similar massed shark.  So an aluminum one should be able to as well. the human skull is not that strong. Just note it can't be *pure* aluminum, it has to be impure either an alloy or composite, truly pure aluminum is ridiculously soft and likely would not survive biting anything. Anything like structural aluminum 3003 or 5056 ([see comparison](https://www.makeitfrom.com/compare/3003-AlMn1Cu-3.0517-A93003-Aluminum/5056-A95056-Aluminum)) will work fine.

note, biting through a skull and biting off a head is very different, a skull is fairly weak the neck on the other hand is a lot tougher. it should still be possible assuming it can actually fit around the skull.

Comment: Good answer, and I appreciate pointing out the difference between crushing a skull and biting through a neck.

Comment: I simply wanted the monster to be able to bite through the skull sufficiently to be able to slice it off cleanly. This is perfect!

Comment: This is perfect! I just want the monster to be able to bite the skull right off, so it's fine. Also, I'll make its teeth an alloy of sorts. As in, I'll make the aluminum alloy most of the tooth plate, with an inner pulp to supply the teeth. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dunkleosteus had a bite force of ~5000 newtons which should be enough to terrorize your world
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2373817/